# Getting data as an input in cpp

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I'm trying to get the user to input data but the compiler skips the getline function in my cpp program.What could be the problem?  Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Customer{

 char name[10];
 char email[30];
 int age ;
 int idno;
 string date;


};

int main()
{
  Customer cust;
   cout<<"Enter the name of the customer"<<endl;
   cin>>cust.name;

   cout<<"Enter the email of the customer"<<endl;
   cin>>cust.email;

   cout<<"Enter the age of the customer"<<endl;
   cin>>cust.age;

   cout<<"Enter the id number of the customer"<<endl;
   cin>>cust.idno;

   cout<<"Enter the date of birth of the customer"<<endl;
   getline(cin,cust.date);


   cout<<"The details of the customer are"<<endl;
   cout<<"Name :"<<cust.name<<endl;
   cout<<"Email :"<<cust.email<<endl;
   cout<<"Age :"<<cust.age<<endl;
   cout<<"Id number :"<<cust.idno<<endl;
   cout<<"Date of birth :"<<cust.date<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

[Here is the output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsUl7.png)

Comment: put the output as text

Comment: Sorry,but the compiler won't allow me to read the date data

Comment: Using `getline` after `>>` doesn't do what you think it will do. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: Why don't you just use a plain `cin>>cust.date`?

Comment: This is because I am trying to read a sentence from the user and not a single string word.In cin the compiler stops reading input the moment you press the space bar.